# Is there a survey that can provide me with Rubedo Leather?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I only reached champion 160 recently and I can create Rubedo Leather items. But these champion 160 items require so many rubedo leather that I keep all the scraps I get. I even avoid any writ that forces me into crafting those items.

But I'm ready to do those writs if I know I can get Rubedo Leather out of the surveys. So is it the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes! As of today (Update 11), tailoring surveys will get you some Leather in addition to raw cloth. However, I'm not sure how lucrative this is.

**Just keep in mind that you're only forced to craft items given a specific material level.** As far as I know you **won't** have to actually craft Champion 160 items. Champion 150 items should do just fine for 1/10<sup>th</sup> the costs.

In case you're playing on console, you'll have to wait until Update 11 hits these platforms (as far as I know mid August 2016).

Comment: Oh, that's great, and very thoughtful of ZOS to make them specially available for me when I reach that champion 160 level. Alas, I play on PS4 so I'll just wait a few weeks more, not a big deal. :-) Yes, yes, I craft level 150 stuff for writs, not the über expensive 160, but thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Confirmed on PS4 since I got a Clothier survey in Wrothgar first day of the patch. Thanks again!